# Allow users to choose strings to be used in email templates in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We have a few email templates in our and a very basic template looks like this:

```
<p> Hi <?= $name?>,</p></br>
<p> A new task has been assigned to you. Please check your tasks list. </p>
```

We need to allow users to insert their own text if they would like to translate the basic texts.

The easiest way would obviously store two strings/translations for every user:

```
"Hi"
"A new task has been assigned to you. Please check your tasks list."
```

and then just to pick them, but the problem arises when a user would for example only like to have the email say: `"New task has been assigned"` without any greating.

Questions is: how can we allow users to store strings including the html tags and names of php variables?

All of the templates are short and include 3 php variables at max.

If there is any other information that is valuable and I can provide, just ask.

Comment: Why not allow users to create and edit their own email template?

Comment: Well, this would sort of work similarly, however since email texts are really short, we have decided to store them in a database. The questions is how to allow user to enter lets say `$name` or any HTML tag and to use them in the actual template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We need to allow users to insert their own text if they would like to
>   translate the basic texts.
>
> ..we have decided to store them in a database

Simple solution.

On frontend allow user to create own email text, and store in db, like:

```
<p> Hi {{name}},</p></br>
<p> A new task has been assigned to you. Please check your tasks list. </p>
<hr>
<p>Best regards,</p>
<p>{{admin}}</p>
<p>{{email}}</p>
```

As you see here is {{name}},{{admin}},{{email}} as variable placeholders.

On backend before render email or html page use str_replace() php function to find variable placeholders and replace with other values:

```
$tpl = $user->template; // load from db
$tpl = str_replace("{{name}}", $user->name, $tpl);
$tpl = str_replace("{{admin}}", $admin->name, $tpl);
$tpl = str_replace("{{email}}", $admin->email, $tpl);

echo $tmpl;
```

or that answered by drmonkeyninja

```
   $tpl = str_replace(
      [
         '{{name}}', 
         '{{admin}}', 
         '{{email}}'
      ],
      [
         $user->name,
         $admin->name,
         $admin->email
      ],
      $user->template // load from db
   );
   echo $tpl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brilliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Store your email template HTML in your database with some form of token to represent changeable data like for your `$name` and then use `str_replace` to substitute the tokens for the real values. For example, if you have tokens in your data like `${name}` and `${message}`:-

```
$body = str_replace(
    [
        '${name}',
        '${message}'
    ], 
    [
        $name,
        'Foo bar'
    ],
    $body
);
```

You can then pass `$body` to `CakeEmail` and send the email as normal.

This is the approach I tend to take with emails when wanting to allow users to customise the text in any email generated by the system and it works well.

Comment: What if user in $body text change order of 'tokens' in template, for example first use ${message} , than ${name} ?

Comment: @Salines it makes no difference, using `str_replace` with arrays like in my example is just a neater way of doing multiple string replacements without having to individually call `str_replace` for each token like in your accepted answer.

Comment: you're right, my mistake, for some reason I was not able to use that approach. In my case variables placeholders must be arranged in the same sequence as in the array. But now I tested on a different server and everything is working properly.